# Darcula look and feel na aplicação

Tags: java, look-and-feel

Olá, 
Utilizo o NetBeans com o plugin gráfico Darcula LAF, para programar Java. Este plugin deixa um design escuro, bem bacana.
Na tela de edição do JFrame o look and feel é herdado:
[image: Darcula LAF]

Porém se eu compilo ele fica com o look and feel que eu geralmente coloco via código (UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha pergunta é, de alguma forma posso herdar este look and feel do plugin?

Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relacione [este jar](https://github.com/Revivius/nb-darcula/raw/master/lib/com/bulenkov/darcula/1.0.0/darcula-1.0.0.jar) na sua *class path*, e então:

```
BasicLookAndFeel darcula = new DarculaLaf();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(darcula);
```

Comment: Bah que simples, Muito obrigado!